Wp_list_table show before html tag
I used this example https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-list-table-example/ to create a front-end page.
It is missing the CSS styling, which I will have to load manually.
The problem is that it loads the content before of the html tag.
In the constructor I added add_action('init', array($this,'my_page'),22);
The function my_page:
function my_page()
{
 global $wpdb;
 $query = new \WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'any', 'name' => 'all-ex-alunni-wp_list_table'));
 $content = $this->init_subscribers();
 if(0 === $query->post_count)
 {
     $post = array(
         'post_title' => 'My wp_list_table',
         'post_name' => 'my-wp_list_table',
         'post_content' => $content,
         'post_status' => 'publish',
         'post_type' => 'page',
     );
     $post_id = wp_insert_post($post);
 }
}


I just tried the code in the plugin and it works out of the box. edit your question to add more details about your aim and what doesn't work in your code.

I am trying to use the wp_list_calse class to create front-end pages.
In the front-end the table is displayed before the  tag.
In admin it works for me too

I think there’s a reason that WP_List_Table lives in the wp-admin folder. I’m not saying it is wrong to use it on the frontend, and there’s definitely people that have done it, I just think the work might not be worth it. Is there a specific reason you want to use it instead of writing a simple HTML table? I’ve built backend things with it, and I even try avoiding it for those scenarios sometimes

I want to display in the frontend a list of users, a personal table of the db, with some useful information for everyone.
The wp_list_table class had everything needed so I was trying that class.
If you know of another method that allows pagination and search I welcome suggestions.

I would just call something like wp_list_users and loop over the results.

The init_subscribers function
function init_subscribers()
{
    global $tale;
    $table = new List_Table_front_end_extended();
    $content = $table->prepare_items();
    $content = $table->search_box( ‘search’, ‘search_id’ );
    $content .= $table->display();
  return $content;
}

In the browser's html source code, the table is inside the body tag
The result

